# Tagging for remote/location recording

Tags: discussion, tags

We need to decide how to tag question related to recording on-location.  Some call this remote recording, others call it location recording.  We have a few options:

- `remote` - if we use this tag for remote recording we need to decide how to tag remote control questions.
- `remote-recording`
- `location-recording`

Any thoughts or other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would vote for 'location-recording'. In general, even if we had a good alternative for 'remote controlled systems', 'remote' is a very ambiguous term and I would really discourage using it. Even 'remote-recording' might be ambiguous, it can even be about recording with a very directional microphone.

Comment: I agree. `location-recording` is an easily parsed term that will  cover live music recording as well as film sound.